# Determine if a Bezier surface contains a specific Bezier curve

Tags: surfaces, bezier-curve

Let's suppose that we have the following Bezier surface 
$$ 
P(t1,t2)=  \sum_{i=0}^{3} {   \sum_{j=0}^{3} p_{ij} { \varphi _{i}(t1) \varphi _{j}(t2) } }  
$$
Is there a way to determine if a specific Bezier curve, let's say:
$$ 
Q(t)=  \sum_{i=0}^{3} p_{i2} { \varphi _{1}(t) } 
$$
belongs to P(t1,t2)?

I know that in order to find if a specific point (x,y) belongs to a Bezier curve, we just need to find a value to that satisfies the equation `P(t=to) = (x,y)`, but in this case is much more difficult.

Is there an easier way than trying to find values for t1 and t2 that satisfy the equation `P(t1=t1x, t2 = t2y) = Q(t)` ?

Comment: Are $p_{i2}$ and $p_{ij}$ with $j=2$ identical ?

Comment: Yes, these are the same control points

Comment: Then in general $Q$ is not included in $P$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a way to prove it maybe?